# if @user.persisted? with Facebook omniauth | Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, devise, omniauth, facebook-oauth

My **Omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb**

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
    def facebook
        # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
        @user ||=
            User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

        if @user.persisted?
            # This will throw if @user is not activated
            sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
            if is_navigational_format?
                set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: "Facebook")
            end
        else
            session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
            redirect_to new_user_registration_url
        end
    end
end
```

No problems, no Logs. BUT when someone tries to Connect via Facebook it throws them simply to the default Registration Form.

```
http://localhost:3000/sign_up#_=_
```

My User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, #:recoverable
         :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable,
                 :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]


    # Facebook Settings
    def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource = nil)
        user = User.where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first
        if user.present?
            user
        else
            user = User.create(first_name:auth.extra.raw_info.first_name,
                                                 last_name:auth.extra.raw_info.last_name,
                                                 facebook_link:auth.extra.raw_info.link,
                                                 provider:auth.provider,
                                                 uid:auth.uid,
                                                 email:auth.info.email,
                                                 password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20])
        end
    end



    validates :first_name, :presence => true
    validates :email, :presence => true
    validates :user_name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true

    has_many :clips
    has_one :show, dependent: :destroy

    # Profile Page Avatar
    has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { avatar: "64x64#"},
                                        :default_url => "http://placehold.it/150x150&text=Missing"

    validates_attachment :avatar,
                                             content_type: { content_type: ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/gif'] },
                                             size: { less_than: 5.megabytes }

    # Profile Page Cover
    has_attached_file :profile_cover, styles: { cover: "870x150#"},
                                        :default_url => "http://placehold.it/150x150&text=Missing"

    validates_attachment :profile_cover,
                                             content_type: { content_type: ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/gif'] },
                                             size: { less_than: 5.megabytes }


    # For Using the username instead of ID in the Link
    def to_param
        user_name
    end

end
```

Comment: Please show your `User.find_for_facebook_oauth`

Comment: Where do i find that ?

Comment: Just follow this tut: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

Comment: Then why no such method in User model?

Comment: There is the method in the Users Model, i Updated my Question

Comment: Got the reason, see my update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure the reason as there are some other info involved.

I would suggest:

1. Change this line

   ```
   @user ||= User.find_for_facebook_oauth ...
   ```

   To

   ```
   @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth
   ```

   This is to eliminate other possible effect, and there is little point to cache @user as this action will not be hit frequently.
2. Make sure you have `provider`, `uid`, `name` columns added and migrated.
3. The reason should be @user is not persisted so there may be something wrong when creating the user. You can change `create` to `create!` to see what error thrown.

   If still not sure, debug into this User method.

**Update**

Okay, got the reason. You have a validation:

```
validates :user_name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
```

But in Facebook attributes, there is no such attribute `:user_name`, so saving will be fail.

Fix is just to use a method to add this attribute to Facebook hash, or not validate this attr.

Comment: Yeap this is the problem :) Thank Billy. In my app i need :user_name how can i set up that user's will be prompt to enter that user_name ?

Comment: @TheMiniJohn, in Facebook hash there is a field "auth.extra.raw_info.name" which can be used as user_name, no need to input again. They will be unique because Facebook has already validated them. But it is still possible this field will meet duplicate in the existing user. To make things simpler you can remove uniqueness validation of this attr. A complex solution is to rescue the `create!` by appending some unique string if duplicate meet, but this is another topic.

Comment: "auth.extra.raw_info.name" Worked for now, but i need a way arround this. I need the uniqueness because :user_name is also called in the link to a User's Profile.
I'm Searching on how to Split the User Registration Proccess, so :user_name can be edited after the Facebook Connect. But Thanks :)